# Is "Do the data..." gramatically correct?

Tags: grammar, grammatical-number, irregular-plurals

For example, in these websites:

- [Do the data exist to make college rating systems work?](https://www.npr.org/2013/08/22/214520122/does-the-data-exist-to-make-college-rating-system-work)
- [Specialization and the Volume of Trade: Do the Data Obey the Laws?](http://www.nber.org/papers/w8675)
- [Immigration: What do the data tell us?](https://data.berkeley.edu/immigration-what-do-data-tell-us)

In all of these cases, replacing "Do" with "Does" makes it sound more natural, but is "Do" correct?

Answer (score 0):

Technically, "data" is a plural, but you seldom see it used that way outside the sciences, and sometimes not even then. From Merriam Webster:

> *Data* leads a life of its own quite independent of *datum*, of which it was originally the plural. It occurs in two constructions: as a plural noun (like *earnings*), taking a plural verb and plural modifiers (such as *these*, *many*, *a few*) but not cardinal numbers, and serving as a referent for plural pronouns (such as *they*, *them*); and as an abstract mass noun (like *information*), taking a singular verb and singular modifiers (such as *this*, *much*, *little*), and being referred to by a singular pronoun (*it*). Both constructions are standard. The plural construction is more common in print, evidently because the house style of several publishers mandates it. [1](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/data)

Comment: Hello, Rodney. As you might expect, this has been answered here before. Several times.

Comment: Ah. Didn't even think about that. :)

Comment: If there were something special about those examples that might distinguish them from the general question linked in the "Possible duplicate" comment, this might stand as a new question. But I don't see the examples in this question as exceptional.